# Element that becomes sticky while scrolling on a Figma prototype

Tags: interaction-design, mobile, prototype, software

I was wondering if it's possible to have a fixed positioned element become sticky to the viewport when you scroll past it on a Figma prototype.

I tried searching for it but I can't seem to find it.

If it's not possible with Figma can you please let me know what tool I should use to whip up a quick prototype with this functionality with?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to UX StackExchange @MACC.

Try this: Select an element and tick the box "Fix position when scrolling" in the right tool pane.

[image]

When creating a prototype in Figma you can define this element as an overlay to add a hover effect (see Figma blog for a detailed description).

Comment: Greenforest, this will make it sticky from the ground-up right? I wanted the element to just become sticky when you scroll past it, up until then it would scroll along with the rest of the elements.